# How do you add existing WPF UI applications to a new WAF solution

Tags: wpf, wcf

I have two working, WCF/WPF, endpoint service and UI client application combinations. The requirement now is to combine the separate UI client applications into one wrapper application that would allow a user to pick which of the front ends they wanted to work with.

It seems like this would be a good point to begin using WAF, but I'm unclear as to how you would merge existing WPF projects in a WAF template (using Visual Studio 2010, and C#). I'm also sure that there's probably another approach that might be a whole lot simplier; something along the lines, perhaps, of a shell command to launch the respective UI executable, but that seems fairly messy (at the very least) when it comes down to deployment issues; though, hopefully, someone will have a better suggestion.

So the bottom line here is: What would you suggest? Keeping in mind that I would like to go with a solution that gets it working (doesn't have to be fancy) in the shortest amount of time.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

WAF separates your application into a domain layer, application layer, and presentation layer. In addition to those three libraries, you will also have a project containing a shell view, shell view model, and a controller.

To fit your two applications, they should follow suit. Your shell view, shell viewmodel, and controller will determine the view and viewmodels to load allowing you to switch the front-ends.

If I remember correctly, the WAF library has a sample for a bookstore or some such. I think it lines up with your needs well.

HTH,